# Hierarchical TabControl

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I would realize a sort of "Hierarchical TabControl" in which there are TabItems as root and all their related children (shown always as TabItem).

I have to realize that using WPF, so I try to write a ContentTemplate of TabItem, using the HierarchicalDataTemplate, but with any result :(

I would like to obtain something like this:
 [image]

Can anyone of you give me some advices?